# Checking for position-dependent duplicates in two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

Apologies is this has already been asked. However I can't seem to find a solution.

I want to check whether elements in the same position within two vectors are identical. Ideally this solution would work for both character and numeric vectors.

Below are some examples of inputs and desired outputs:

```
numeric <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
FUNCTION(numeric, rev(numeric))

#### OUTPUT ####
[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

```
character <- c("I","AM","HAPPY")
FUNCTION(character, rev(character))

#### OUTPUT ####
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Just use `numeric == rev(numeric)` or `character == rev(character)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test with == if they are equal and iterate through all positions:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "text")
b <- c("a", "b1", "c", "text")

c <- a[]==b[]
```

Output:

```
# > print(a)
# [1] "a"    "b"    "c"    "text"
# > print(b)
# [1] "a"    "b1"   "c"    "text"
# > print(c)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```